# get particular index from user_ind_column table

Tags: oracle

I have to take particular index information from user_ind_column table and that index should be bitmap index

how to active this scenario

could any one assist me

```
IEA_PATIENT_PK      _PATIENT    HIEA_PATIENT_ID 1   40  40  ASC
IEA_PATIENT_PK      _PATIENT    BATCH_ID    2   22  0   ASC
IEA_PATIENT_IDX2    _PATIENT    HIEA_PATIENT_ID 1   40  40  ASC
IEA_PATIENT_IDX2    _PATIENT    PRACTICE_NAME   2   4000    4000    ASC
IN_HIEA_PATIENT     _PATIENT    HIE_ID  1   22  0   ASC
IN_XHIEA_PATIENT    _PATIENT    HIE_ID  1   22  0   ASC
IN_XHIEA_PATIENT    _PATIENT    PRACTICE_NAME   2   4000    4000    ASC
```

these are index information against _PATIENT table but i need to take IN_HIEA_PATIENT record from table with out using index name

Thanks
pandia

Comment: Clear as mud. What do you know (what are the inputs) and what do you need? Do you have a table name, and do you need to find all indexes on that table that are bitmap indexes? Can you formulate some simple thoughts in a logical, understandable succession?

Comment: Actually i have to create a bitmap index for _PATIENT table on hie_id column if that table contain those index already then i dont need to create it again, so i need check whether any bitmap index are created for that column or not 
Can you get may point? @mathguy

Comment: You can simply create the index. If such column is already indexed you get an exception

Answer (score 0):

This, perhaps? (Proof of concept - searching for bitmap indexes and their associated columns; what is given is the schema name, `'SH'`, and the table name, `'COSTS'`; `'SH'` is one of the standard Oracle schemas, found in most database installations).

```
select index_name, column_name
from dba_ind_columns
where index_name in (
                      select index_name
                      from   dba_indexes 
                      where  index_type  = 'BITMAP'
                         and table_owner = 'SH'
                         and table_name  = 'COSTS'
                    )  
;

INDEX_NAME      COLUMN_NAME
--------------  -----------
COSTS_TIME_BIX  TIME_ID
COSTS_PROD_BIX  PROD_ID
```

Comment: Actually i have to create a bitmap index for _PATIENT table on hie_id column if that table contain those index already then i dont need to create it again, so i need check whether any bitmap index are created for that column or not

Comment: @PANDIALAKSHMANAN -  So, then, the solution I proposed should help you - it will show you all the bitmap indexes on the table, including the name of the column they are on.

Comment: Yes that solution giving me some close answer but if i have 2 bitmap index on the same table, one index has created on _id column and other index created for some other columns then it would display both index name right. but i need the index name which has created particularly on _id column @mathguy and thanks for your reply

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL at all? What you need is a WHERE clause to select only the rows where the column name is the column you want, can you do that yourself? This is not a free "write ALL the code for me" web site!